# Find $a,b$ for which the function is continuous at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Determine the values of $a,b$ for which the function is continuous at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$
>   $$
> f(x) = 
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{1-\sin^3x}{3\cos^2x} & \text{if} \ x<\frac{\pi}{2} \\ \\
> a & \text{if} \ x=\frac{\pi}{2}  \\ \\
> \frac{b(1-\sin x)}{(\pi-2x)^2} &\text{if} \ x>\frac{\pi}{2} \ 
> \end{cases}.
> $$

Can you help me with this problem?

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1-\sin^3(\frac{\pi}{2}-h)}{3\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{2}-h)}$$
and$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{b(1-\sin h)}{(\pi-2h)^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, I would use $\sin (\frac \pi 2 - h)=\cos(h)$ and the other to get the expansion around zero, then use the Taylor series for $\sin, \cos$

For the second you need the limit at $h \to \frac \pi 2$, not $0$.  I would again move let $h = \frac \pi 2 + g$, swap the trig function in the numerator, and use the Taylor series.

Comment: What is taylor's series? can u elaborate?

Comment: Taylor's series is an approximation for a function near a point.  For $\sin x$ near zero it is $\sin x = x-\frac {x^3}{3!} + \frac {x^5}{5!}\ldots.$   My other try would be [L'Hopital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)  where you take the derivative of numerator and denominator, but that comes about the same time.